# How to ensure #include doesn't recursively add (only adds unique files once)

Tags: c++, header, include-guards, cyclic-dependency

I have this file `main.h` and this file `events.h`, the file `events.h` needs to include `main.h` as the singleton of my `Events` class requires my singleton of my `Main` class in order to declare `Main` as a `friend` class, so it can access `Events` private members/methods.

Conversely, `Main` also needs to include `Events` to call its methods, however doing `#include "events.h"` in main, and then `#include "main.h"` in events will just recursively keep pasting the header file code in each of them.

How can I avoid this so that each of them only pastes the code in *once* per file?

**main.h**

```
#ifndef MAIN_H
#define MAIN_H

#include "events.h"

class Main
{
public:
    Main(const Main&) = delete;
    Main(Main&&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(const Main&) = delete;
    Main& operator=(Main&&) = delete;


    static void Mainloop();




private:
    Main()
    {
        std::cout << "Main constructor called\n";
        mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'C';
    }

    static Main& Get_Instance()
    {
        static Main instance;
        return instance;
    }


    static void Init();
    static void Free();



    SDL_Window* window = nullptr;
    SDL_Renderer* renderer = nullptr;

    bool running = false;
    char mainloopInstanceBlocker = 'I';



};








#endif // MAIN_H
```

**events.h**

```
#ifndef EVENTS_H
#define EVENTS_H


#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <string>


#include "main.h"


class Events
{
public:
    Events(const Events&) = delete;
    Events(Events&&) = delete;
    Events& operator=(const Events&) = delete;
    Events& operator=(Events&&) = delete;



    static const std::string& User_Text_Input();




private:
    Events()
    {
        std::cout << "Events constructor called\n";
    }

    static Events& Get_Instance()
    {
        static Events instance;
        return instance;
    }


    friend class Main;

    ///For event handling
    static void Event_Loop()
    {
        Get_Instance();

        if (Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter == 0)
        {

            Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter += 1;

            while (SDL_PollEvent(&Get_Instance().event))
            {
                if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_QUIT)
                {
                    Get_Instance().m_quit = true;
                    break;
                }
                else if (Get_Instance().event.type == SDL_TEXTINPUT)
                {
                    Get_Instance().m_User_Text_Input = Get_Instance().event.text.text;
                }


            }

        }
    }

    ///For event handling
    static void Reset_Events()
    {
        Get_Instance().eventLoopCounter = 0;

        Get_Instance().m_quit = false;
        Get_Instance().m_User_Text_Input = "";
    }

    ///For quitting, used main only
    static bool Quit_Application(){
        return Get_Instance().m_quit;
    }



    ///For Event_Loop()
    int eventLoopCounter = 0;
    SDL_Event event;




    bool m_quit = false;

    std::string m_User_Text_Input = "";



};



#endif // EVENTS_H
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are forward declarations in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4757565/what-are-forward-declarations-in-c) In particular, see "Break cyclic references where two definitions both use each other" in the top answer.

Comment: Also: [Resolve build errors due to circular dependency amongst classes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/625799/resolve-build-errors-due-to-circular-dependency-amongst-classes)

Comment: I'm not sure if my ```#ifndef``` helps, I don't know whether or not the code its pasted recursively due to this (as one of the answers says to do this), im on Code::Blocks. I know how to do it on Visual Studio ( to see the generated code after compiling ) but I don't have it,.

Comment: The other part is, I need my class to be a singleton, not publicly available in anything except ```Main```. Would forward declaring it in ```Main``` affect anything of those sorts of things?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a linker and header file problem, you just need to add `#pragma once` at the top of each header files, the compiler will add the content of each header files only one time, but you must ensure that you just declare methods in your header files and write the content of those methods in other `.cpp` files to prevent of linking error.

Comment: Does this mean I can't define methods in the header?

Comment: Yes, that's right. Because it will cause a linking error and the terminal will print an error like this: function "func_name" is defined more than one time.

Comment: `#pragma once`.

Comment: How can I define methods in the .cpp file? Not the usual ones, but something that returns the instance of its own class, for example, in the code, ```static Main& Get_Instance()``` I don't know how to declare that

Comment: To maintain it as static

Comment: Oh, also, the constructor, Its 'deleted' but also defined in my header. How can I do the same for that

Comment: I have code that works but im more unsure if its a singleton/works the same way. Declaring it as static in the header lets me know for sure its all static

Comment: if I add ```#pragma once``` to the top, do I remove the ```#ifndef ...``` ```#define ...```? If not do I put it above or below one of them?